# How do I use the Google classroom API to transfer ownership of a class to another teacher without the original teacher's account

Tags: google-classroom

One of my teachers at my school left without transferring ownership of their class to the co teacher. I was told that as an admin I can transfer the ownership but must use the Google classroom API. I haven't used an API before so am struggling to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

If you are a G Suite admin you can achieve this by using the method `courses.patch` ([here you can find how to use/implement it](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/patch)) updating the `ownerId` in the `updateMask` of the query parameters of that PATCH request.

You can achieve all this in your preferred programming language or even in Apps Script if you find it more comfortable. [In the API Guides](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started) you can find a quick start guide for using the Google Classroom API in your favourite language, for example [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/apps-script) is the quickstart using Apps Script.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Thank you for this... I ran the quickstart but truth be told I don't know what that achieved other than maybe turning on the google classroom API. It may be that I simply don't know enough about programming to do this, but where I am supposed to be changing the `ownerId` and the `updatemask`, what exactly am I supposed to be changing from and to? Some sort of step by step or video tutorial would be incredibly helpful. Thanks

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIfXzJMLsMQ&list=PLhwqGNyxZTb7gDd4xXF2J4duasiktmAbR) might be useful to you then :)

Comment: I've read that in my case the orphaned google classroom class cannot be transferred to another teacher, but deleting it is an option. However when I used the method:courses.delete API and typed in the `courseID` as it is named in the google classroom app, it keeps returning error 404: not found. Can you advise if I need to change/add something to my API in order for it to execute correctly?

Comment: Could you please show me a sample of your piece of code? (please, don't include any sensitive data)

Comment: So I am using the API explorer on the google classroom API page, I haven't written an entire script myself, simply added the codes in to the automated API editor... I have managed to use the `courses.get` and have found the class code, which has the `ownerId` attached but this Id no longer exists in our organisation. So I have tried the `courses.delete` and the `courses.update` in both instances it returned _error 500: internal error encoutnered_ The only thing that I haven't yet tried to execute is the update mask, as I am not sure what the field mask should read?

Comment: "id": "17591393882",
  "name": "8EB1 Science",
  "descriptionHeading": "8EB1",
  "ownerId": "105250506097979753968",
  "creationTime": "2018-09-05T09:53:44.114Z",
  "updateTime": "2018-09-05T10:08:56.099Z",
  "enrollmentCode": "e2zwoue",
  "courseState": "ACTIVE",

 Here is most of the code in the request body, I just need to change this current ownerId to one of the teachers that is still here...

Comment: Hi ! This erratic behaviour you are encountering seems to be a bug that has already been reported. You can find a link to it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760244) . I hope this information will help you understand what is going on :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a lot easier if, as an administrator, you reset the password of the google account of the teacher who left. Then log in as her/him, and transfer ownership of the classroom to whomever you need to.

Comment: Unfortunately the staff account was deleted from the domain. So this wasn’t possible. I read online this situation is referred to as an “orphaned classroom” so doesn’t seem to be possible as far as I can tell. Thanks anyway